# Does the pigeonhole principle (Schubfachprinzip/drawer principle) depend on the law of the excluded middle?

Tags: logic

The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) seems self-evident, most people would accept it without evidence, but I wonder if we wanted to prove it, would we have to use the excluded middle principle?
I would be grateful to provide a proof with or without the excluded middle principle, but I am curious as to which proof does not use the excluded middle principle.

Comment: can you state the principle?

Comment: [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Etymology)

Comment: Are you talking about the finite version? Which definition of finite are you using? Note that there are no "canonical" definition of a set being finite without excluded middle.